# FuelPHPでopauth/twitterを実行するとTwitterの認証画面に遷移しない

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, fuelphp

現在、FuelPHP 1.8 にてTwitter認証の仕組みを作っています。

ドキュメントに従い、Controllerで \Auth_Opauth::forge() を実行すると直接 Callback URL に飛んで行くようです。

環境は、
エックスサーバー
PHP 7.0.3
FuelPHP 1.8

opauthのインストールは Composer を使っています。

```
"opauth/opauth": "0.4.*",
"opauth/twitter": "dev-master",
"opauth/facebook": "dev-master"
```

Controller のコードは下記のとおりです。

```
class Controller_Oauth extends Controller
{
  public function action_login($provider = null)
  {
    if ($provider === null)
    {
      \Messages::error('login-no-provider-specified');
      \Response::redirect_back();
    }

    \Auth_Opauth::forge();
  }

  public function action_facebook()
  {
    //
  }

  public function action_callback()
  {
    $opauth = \Auth_Opauth::forge(false);
  }
}
```

Strategy の設定は
/path/to/app/config/opauth.php

```
'Twitter' => array(
  'key' => 'gFEQjKSP3apYH6X83JPdFtej7',
  'secret' => ' kzcjoSCrgtPifMqyt7Pkw2tIReKY0gSCP6fnOpJnTe3prQpzxL'
),
```

callback アクションで var_dump($opauth) すると、opauthの設定がオブジェクトとして返ってきます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

同様の問題でどっぷりハマり解決したので共有します。
fuel/vendor/opauth/twitter/Vendor/tmhOAuth/tmhOAuth.php
の最終行付近で

```
\Log::debug(__METHOD__.' '.__LINE__.' $this->response =  '.print_r($this->response, TRUE));
```

してresponse内容を確認すると

```
[error] => SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled
[errno] => 35
```

と出ているのではないかと思います。
下記に記しているのは、このエラーを解決した内容です。
おそらくcurlのSSLがOpenSSLではなく、SecureTransport ではないかと思います。

```
$ php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => SecureTransport
```

と出ていたらその通りで、これをOpenSSLに変更します。

自分の場合はMacなので、brewで別途curlをインストール

```
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
〜中略〜
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include
```

これを使って curl.so をソースからコンパイルし直す
https://www.php.net/releases/ より 自身のPHPのバージョンと同じソースをダウンロード

```
$ cd /usr/local/src
$ tar xjvf php-x.x.xx.tar.bz2
$ cd /usr/local/src/php-x.x.x/ext/curl
$ phpize
(先ほどbrew経由で出たLDFLAGSやCPPFLAGSの値を入れてconfigure)
$ ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"
$ make
$ make test
$ sudo make install
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

再びcurlのSSL確認

```
$ php -i | grep "SSL Version"
SSL Version => OpenSSL/x.x.x
```

この後OpauthでTwitterが通るようになりました。